# multiline textview in android

Tags: android, textview

in this activity, i have two textview
in first textview, the last line has only two character so it looks like some odd.

so i want to check the last line of textview, and if the number of character in last line is less than 10 then i want to remove that character from line 1.

so how can i get the last line characters?
help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you are using EditTextView or TextView for this.

If so,

1. you take the data using getText() for the view.
2. use [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) and go to the last line.
3. Check if you have less than 10 characters
4. Do your task or removing.

Comment: thanx dear, i get the sollution